# Regex comma delimited string with specific characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a pattern that will match each character in a comma delimited string and make sure it is one of a specific set of characters

Specific set of characters = `A, B, C`

I'm pretty new to regex so it would be nice if you could break down how this works as well please :)

**Example**

The following strings **should match**
`A`
`A,B`
`A,B,C,B,A,B,C`

The following strings **should not match**
`D`
`A,D`
`A,B,C,B,B,A,D`

Comment: Use: `^[ABC](?:,[ABC])*$`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the entire string (and not any groups within), you can simply match a string containing any number of the specified characters plus commas:

```
^[ABC][ABC,]*$
```

Edit: If you need to ensure you're not matching double letters (e.g., `A,B,CC, A` *shouldn't* match), then you could group that particular pattern:

```
^[ABC](,[ABC])*$
```